# Filling color in a CAShapeLayer from left to right

Tags: ios, core-animation, cashapelayer

For my current project, I need to draw a custom chart similar to the picture attached. I am using `CABasicAnimation` with `strokeEnd` property to stroke the path with animation. I am facing problem to fill the lower portion of the dashed line with color with *animation*. I need to **fill the content of the `CAShapeLayer` with color from left to right** following the same animation timing function for stroking the path of the layer. Can anyone please help me?

[image]